# double output for variable

Tags: php, dump, var-dump

I have this next function:

```
function checkLoggedIn($status, $redirect=TRUE){
    switch($status){
        case "yes":
            if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedIn"])){
                if($redirect) {
                    header("Location: login.php");
                    exit;
                } else {
                    $authenticated = false;
                }
            } else {
                checkLoggedIn("no");
            }
        break;

        case "no":
            if(isset($_SESSION["loggedIn"]) && $_SESSION["loggedIn"] === true ){
                $authenticated = true;
            }
        break;
    }
    var_dump($authenticated);
    return $authenticated;
}
```

The strange this is that when I enable `var_dump($authenticated);`, I get as output if `true`:

```
bool(true)
NULL
```

and just

```
bool(false)
```

if `false`

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you are calling `checkLoggedIn()` inside itself.

Comment: oh, I see.. then, any ideas how to avoid the double response?

Comment: I'd say put the `case "no"` code directly in the `else` statement instead of calling the function again.

Comment: bufff, almost impossible because of the way that it was implemented (not by me). I'll find a solution, eventually! Thanks